# Spring 4 MVC and Websockets - No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, websocket

I need Websockets for real-time updates in my application. So i found this example and did it step by step [here](http://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/using-spring-4-websocket-sockjs-and-stomp-support-to-implement-two-way-server-client-communication/). I went through the tutorial and finally i got this exception when starting the application:

> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
> ```
>
> 'org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler#0':
> Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
> instantiate bean class
> [org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default
> RequestUpgradeStrategy found

I have searched a lot, but i didn't find a solution.

I hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

best regards, patrick

Answer (score 30):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.52</version>
</dependency>
```

As pointed by Craig Otis, if you're planning on deploying to Tomcat anyway, you should use `<scope>test</scope>` to ensure you don't include the dependency in your build artifact.

Comment: This worked for me, when seeing `No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found` as part of our JUnit tests. Note that if you're planning on deploying to Tomcat anyway, you should use `<scope>test</scope>` to ensure you don't include the dependency in your build artifact.

Comment: my spring mvc project have this error now.Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ServletContext is required to access the javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer instance

Answer (score 6):

I was facing this issue while running websockets in IDE using embedded Jetty, fixed this after adding the below dependencies to pom.xml

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.4.RC0</version>
                <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.4.RC0</version>
                <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.4.RC0</version>
                <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I lost a lot of time digging out for the solution, what i found was that spring websocket will only run over **Tomcat 7.0.47+, Jetty 9.1+, GlassFish 4.1+, WebLogic 12.1.3+, and Undertow 1.0+ (and WildFly 8.0+)** according to spring's documentation shown here 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html, so try updating your app server

Answer (score 2):

The version of Tomcat that you are using is too old.

Upgrade tomcat.  http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Comment: I was using Tomcat7 and was receiving this error. Upgrading to Tomcat8 solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this problem, got across a link see if this is helpful https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/issues/21

Comment: This linked saved me! Apparently I only have the tomcat-embed-core, el, and logging-juli jars in my path! I need the tomcat-embed-websocket jar too :D

Answer (score 1):

The exception means DefaultHandshakeHandler cannot find a supported servers (e.g. Tomcat 7 & 8, Jetty 9). Refer to the javadoc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/server/support/DefaultHandshakeHandler.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Addition,

If you are using gradle, You should add below dependency in `build.gradle`

`compile 'org.projectreactor:reactor-spring:1.0.1.RELEASE'`